# Elasticsearch restore single index from snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-cloud

Before I go an do something stupid, can I double check something with other Elastic users:

My cluster has 2000+ indexes. I've messed up just one of them and need to restore it from a snapshot. If I select that one index to restore, I just want to be sure I'm not going to end up with a cluster with just that index and my other 1999+ missing.

I would imagine the opposite will happen, the 1999+ will remain untouched and just that one will be restored, but I need to be sure before I hit go.

I'm using Elastic Cloud if it has any bearing on things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_restore)

> By default, all indices in the snapshot are restored, and the cluster
>   state is not restored. It’s possible to select indices that should be
>   restored as well as to allow the global cluster state from being
>   restored by using indices and include_global_state options in the
>   restore request body

So with the good restore query it will run smoothly and only restore the missing index.

Answer (score 4):

When you restore single index from elasticsearch snapshot, then only the single index will be restored and rest of the indices will remain untouched.

You can [restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html) single index from elasticsearch snapshot using below command:

```
curl -X POST "<es_endpoint>/_snapshot/<repository_name>/<snapshot_name>/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "indices": "<index_to_restore>",
}
'
```